# What is the purpose of these shunt capacitors on the I2C bus?

Tags: i2c

The application note on page 13 of the [PCA9600 I2C extender/buffer datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9600.pdf) shows pulldown capacitors C2 on the logic-level side of the I2C bus.  I thought with I2C you want to minimize capacitance in the system to maintain sharp rises. What is the purpose of C2, and why does it increase with greater cable capacitance?

[image: PCA 9600 i2c schematic]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those aren't actual caps you should put in. They represent the maximum capacitance of the bus wires between the PCA9600 and the master/slave.

If the cable capacitance is higher, the maximum clock speed is lower and that means those "C2 caps" may also be larger.